# Windows Updates Kill Print-To-PDF-Function (KB4574727, KB4565351, KB4571709)

Tags: pdf, print-to-pdf

for three months now, after installing Windows Updates on our clients (after patchday), one cannot use any print-to-pdf-features. After uninstalling the updates (KB4574727, KB4565351, KB4571709), it works again. While the updates are installed, neither Microsoft PDF Printer, nor other PDF-Printers (such as PDF24Creator's PDF-Printer) work. The print-jobs go into the queue and one gets a message, that an error has occoured. The print-jobs stay in the queue. SAVING as PDF still works, PRINTING as PDF doesn't. Of Course, uninstalling security updates is not an option. So are there any Workarounds? Print-To-PDF is needed here. Not to be misunderstood: the features are not gone (Microsoft PDF Printer is still installed), they just don't work. It doesn't have anything to do with group policies, as far as I can tell.

Help would be very much appreciated. If the problem has been solved in another thread, a link would be sufficient (unfortunately this is not a good topic to search the internet, because there are far too many unrelated problems discussed).

Best regards,

Comment: I forgot to mention: this concerns Windows 10 1803 and 1909. These are the versions we use, so I cannot say if this problem also occurs on other Win10-Version.

Comment: The MS Print to PDF driver is severely broken. However, installing some other print-to-PDF driver (Adobe, FoxIt, PDF995, etc.) seems to generally work OK. (Although we've had the occasional hiccup with Adobe's.)

Comment: I have up to date Windows (V2004) and Office 365 and Print to (Microsoft) PDF works fine.  Have you tried updating everything to see?  Try as test machine.

Comment: As I wrote: ALL PDF-Printers are broken, not just Microsoft PDF. 20.04 is not an option yet, since we first have to come up with group policies and a test-environment for 20.04. That takes time. We will probably skip 20.04 altogether and upgrade to a following version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment. Hence, I am adding it as an answer. First, I would like to know, whether other physical printers are working? In my case all printers are not working after every restart even now. I started having this  problem after windows reset. After every restart, the status of all printers including Microsoft print to pdf and print to onenote for windows 10 is shown as " not connected". I couldn't solve the problem. But, a work around to get the printers connected is as follows. This is to be done after every restart.

Start onenote for windows 10.

Print something from one note selecting Print to PDF as printer.
In the dialogue box specify the place.
All the printers including print to PDF will now be connected and working.
I have no clue as to why it is happening but it has got something to do with driver for " print to onenote for windows 10" printer.

I would like to know why this is happening and to get a permanent solution for this.